# Files with no extension that "Cortana" makes on the regular

Tags: windows-explorer, cortana

Ok so my first question should be obvious, what purpose do these files without an extension serve? and why is the program cortana generating them?

Which brings me to my second not so obvious question, I don't need this program it lame asf and I cant see it in the list in the control panel, how do I delete it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok so my first question should be obvious, what purpose do these files without an extension serve? and why is the program cortana generating them?

Cortana didn’t generate them AppVerif.exe generated them.  They are also from your previous Windows installation and can be safely deleted.

Due to their location they are likely application icon cache files.

> Application Verifier (AppVerif.exe) is a dynamic verification tool for user-mode applications. This tool monitors application actions while the application runs, subjects the application to a variety of stresses and tests, and generates a report about potential errors in application execution or design.

Source: [Application Verifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/application-verifier)